# How to make blurred gradient background like the one on tailwindcss.com?

Tags: css, web, tailwind-css

I want to set background on my website like the one one tailwindcss.com. How can I accomplish this?

[Tailwind Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Gqu.png)

Still wondering how is this implemented.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? Would you like to know how to make the grid behind the background or the gradient itself? Do you already have a gradient background? Does it need to be blurred? How do you want to do it and what have you already tried? This is so I can give you a proper answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Having inspected the Tailwind website for you, it appears they use a [simple JPG image as the header background](https://tailwindcss.com/_next/static/media/hero-dark@90.dba36cdf.jpg). Since it's not SVG, I can't know how it was made.

Comment: However, if they tell us what they properly want, we can do it with css. It's not difficult, yet they haven't given us a proper description.

Comment: @LashenDharmadasa Actually they have, it's the now linked image.

Comment: No, except we don't know what they've already tried. Nor if they want a grid behind it. Nor their attempt code.

Comment: @LashenDharmadasa Thay said they wonder how this is implemented. Is not showing your work in questions banned? (I'm pretty new here, 32 reputation)

Comment: Ok then I shall give them a different approach, thank you :)

Comment: Oh I get it, it is not banned to show your work in questions, it helps everyone else know what approaches you have taken and what works and does not work for your needs!

Comment: @LashenDharmadasa Have a great day!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250768/discussion-between-lashen-dharmadasa-and-gugalcrom123).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, a different approach to @Gugalcrom123's, is to use a css gradient.

Method 1. You can use a website such as this:
https://cssgradient.io/ to come up with the gradient and set that as a background. The website also generates you the code you can use to set it as the background, as well as a regular color fallback in case your browser does not support it. This is where Tailwind probably decided to use method 2.

Method 2. You can use GIMP, Photoshop or some similar drawing tool to draw a gradient, and put it as an image. You can also use `Filter: blur()` on the img in css to blur it with pixels or even use your drawing tool to blur it out! To make the grid, you can do a similar thing, except after drawing the grid, put it behind the gradient layer and set the gradient layer's opacity to something lower than 100%, so the grid shows behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can blur it using a filter: blur(10px); on CSS... But be careful, it might make your site slow.

Also, have a look at SVG FILTERS here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/why-the-svg-filter-is-awesome/